# Substitute Function in Excel VBA for cell range

Tags: vba, excel, string-substitution

I have to replace one character with another in Excel file.

I have used following `Replace` function, but due to exceeds of 1024 character limit in some cells, it stops there.

```
Sub Replace()

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A629")   

      .Cells.Replace ",", ";", xlPart, xlByRows, False

    End With

End Sub
```

I got to know `Substitute` function would do

```
Cells(1, 2) = "=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"","","";"")"
```

But how do I use that for cell range?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Replace()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A629")

    For Each cell In rng
        cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, ",", ";")
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try this.  Note that it uses the VBA `Replace` function, so you need to rename your 'Replace` subroutine.

```
Sub ReplaceText()

    For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A629").Cells

      c = Replace(c.Value, ",", ";")

    Next c

End Sub
```

Note: This will only work if you have values in the cells, no Formulas.  Because Excel has a formula [length limit of 1024 characters](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx).  But given you have this specific error, your cells must not be formulas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It gives an `Compile error : Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment `. But arguments should be fined as per Function I believe.

Comment: Strange, it ran for me on Excel 2010.  Did you change the name of the sub to `ReplaceText`?  What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I am using 2003. Yes used Subroutine as `ReplaceLengthyText `. Can it be version issue?

Comment: Try the above code, it's been updated, although I see you have an answer.  It should work for 2003 as well.  I would argue that my method is neater, since you are using native VBA code... and my guess is that it would run faster too.

Comment: Appreciated your response. But still I am getting the same compile error. It basically complains about the `Replace ` method. Still struggling ti figure it out. Did you try it in 2003 version?